# Sharepoint 2013 Timer Service extremely high CPU usage

Tags: 2013, owstimer, timer-jobs

We are running a sharepoint 2013 on our server and it uses extreme high cpu every now and then. The only way to get rid of it so far is by restarting the service. However this is of course not feasable. can anyone help me figure out what i can do to fix this...

Comment: You need to investigate it further using the SharePoint log.The tool that you need would be the ULS Viewer over here microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=44020. Select File->Open From->ULS and it will start tracking your log in real time. Reproduce the error, get the correlation id and filter the log by it. Look for the Unexpected or Critical Level events. These are the errors that have occurred. This will give you the idea of what actual error you are facing.

Comment: You can also go to Central Admin and check out the timer job status page and see if you've got any jobs that are failing repeatedly around the time of the memory usage or looping all the time.

Comment: Graham, all though it is a good idea to do so, it is nearly impossible to reach any page within sharepoint at that moment. It takes up to 15 minutes to load the homepage...

Comment: You need to stop the SPTimer Service first. After that you can use the uls.